# Change Cells without Copy/Paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

Imagine the list being a lot longer... Is there a way to replace the cells in both A & B with the appropriate name/ID from Column C? "Appropriate Name" is whats in column C (match names). [This is final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRpGV.jpg) YES COPY/PASTE WORKS, but when this whole thing is 5000 long and column C isn't in perfect order, it takes many hours.

[image]

Comment: I made up the names quickly because my actual list of names is about 1000 rows and that's why copy/paste or find/replace will take too long.

Comment: What is an "appropriate name"? Please [edit] and give an example of what the table looks like **after** the desired changes).

Comment: Highlight A and B, rightclick, delete... I am really curious as to why copy and paste can't be used...

Answer (score 0):

Using vba you can substitute the looked up value this way
Adjust the range to point where your substitute values are and the Range of the items you are looking up

```
Sub substituteLookedUp()
Dim myStr As String
Dim matchDbl As Double
Dim Rng As Range
   Set Rng = Range("C1:C10")

   For Each cell In Range("a1:b12")
      If cell <> "" Then
           myStr = Mid(cell, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", cell) + 1, Len(cell) - WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", cell)) & "_" & Left(cell, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", cell) - 1) & "*"
           matchDbl = WorksheetFunction.Match(myStr, Rng, 0)
           newStr = Range("C" & matchDbl)
         Else: newStr = ""
       End If
     cell.Value = newStr
   Next
```

End Sub